# Creating a custom control in EXTjs

Tags: extjs

I have an app where I want to position x and y values in a database using a visual control

how do I go about creating a control which reads the json array and positions boxes that can be resized and moved about.

When the resizing and moving is stopped i'd like to do a json request to update the positions of the x and y coordinates.

Is there a similar widget available or existing demos that i can combine to achieve that effect.

Comment: the latest one. i've not started yet. but i know it's control that's too custom to be part of it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check [this](http://superdit.com/2010/09/30/sticky-notes-using-extjs-window-and-html5-web-sql-database/) article (uses windows). Although, it's ExtJS 3, I don't think it is difficult to implement the same for ExtJS 4.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060148/how-to-drag-panels-in-main-panel/7060214#7060214) question addresses similar issue for ExtJS 4 Although, without saving to database, it could be added pretty easy.